# Detect Hama IR Remote Protocol

Tags: infrared, protocol, ir-receiver

I'm working on an universal receiver and I'm  not able to detect what protocol is used by the Hama VRC-1100 MCE Remote. The signal is this:

[image: Hama VRC-1100]

The Time/Div is set to 2 mS and the distance between a sequence and another is about 49 mS. Because of the IR receiver the signal is inverted.

It seem use the Manchester Code but from what I see the code is neither RC5 or RC6.

**What protocol is it? Is it a standard protocol or not?**

Comment: That is the trace for one function, and I'd agree that it's likely manchester encoded, however once trace for a function which you don't name won't give anyone enough clues to decode it for you. If you capture traces for a dozen or more of the buttons on the remote and group them you may find a pattern and you may understand the protocol. I expect you'll find it always has the same preamble - a break followed by a sequence of 1010 or similar.  Beyond that, though, it may not follow any particular standard protocol.

Comment: I'll certainly do as you say. I've asked because I wanted to be sure that this is a uncommon protocol and don't wasting time trying to decodify a protocol that's already known.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be an example of the MCE protocol, which is a modified form of RC5/6 wherein the normal toggle bit is always 0, there is a new separate toggle bit, and there are two added fields, CCode and Data. See below for a comparison. [image: RC5,RC6, and MCE protocol comparison]